# Repo sync different branches

Tags: android, git, repository, repo

I have to work with different android versions like Ice Cream Sandwitch, KitKat, CyanogenMods and so one. Do I have to make different folders and for every branch/tag sync every time and wait 4 hours per branch? Is there a way to optimize? Is there a way to switch branches similarly to git checkout? Or I always have to make new folder and call "repo init "?

Answer (score 0):

If you frequently switch between different branches it might be easier to have separate workspaces. Otherwise, just switch between manifest branches in the same workspace:

```
repo init -b some-other-branch
repo sync
```

Note that this will rebase all current topic branches onto their new bases.

If you know that all required gits are up to date and that you don't need to hit the network, feel free to run `repo sync -l` instead. Keep in mind that there are corner cases where doing so will end you up with an inconsistent workspace, so be careful. A full sync will be quite quick if your workspace was reasonably up to date to begin with.

To speed up initial workspace creations you can just copy an existing workspace into a new directory. Another option is to create a local mirror from which you can sync any number of workspaces without ever hitting the network; see http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#using-a-local-mirror.